Query returning more rows than expected with nested where clause
Edit
Figured out out:
select distinct on (c.id)
    c.id
from bv.chat c
left join bv.junction_user_chat juc1
    on juc1.chat_id = c.id
left join bv.junction_user_chat juc2
    on juc2.chat_id = c.id
where c.is_admin_chat = false
and (
        (juc1.user_id = 1 and juc2.user_id = 3)
    or
        (juc1.user_id = 3 and juc2.user_id = 1)
);


Suppose the following:
create schema bv;
create table bv.user (
  id integer
);
create table bv.chat (
  id integer,
  is_admin_chat boolean
);
create table bv.junction_user_chat (
  user_id integer,
  chat_id integer
);

insert into bv.user values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
insert into bv.chat values (101, false), (102, false), (103, false);
insert into bv.junction_user_chat values
  (1, 101),
  (1, 102),
  (1, 103),
  (2, 101),
  (3, 102),
  (4, 103);

I'd like to get the chat ID between users 1 and 3, which is 102. Here's my query:
select distinct on (c.id)
    c.id
from bv.chat c
left join bv.junction_user_chat juc1
    on juc1.user_id = 1
left join bv.junction_user_chat juc2
    on juc2.user_id = 3
where c.is_admin_chat = false
and (
        (juc1.user_id = 1 and juc2.user_id = 3)
    or
        (juc1.user_id = 3 and juc2.user_id = 1)
);

However, this returns:
id
101
102
103

But I need this to return:
id
102

What am I doing wrong?

left join should be inner join?

Figured it out:) I was joining on the wrong column. And yes, I need a left join, because a junction record may not always exist for both users at the same time

I think as an aside when you put criteria in your where clause to test values on the left side of your left join, you effectively turn your left joins into inner joins: juc1.user_id = 1 and juc2.user_id = 3 (since now "nulls" on the left side will all be filtered out)
